# What word means to feel better by writing about what you feel?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

What word means "to feel better by writing it down?" Usually speaking about your emotions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Catharsis** is ([Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/catharsis))

> 1. the purging of the emotions or relieving of emotional tensions, especially through certain kinds of art, as tragedy or music.

See, for example, *[Why Write? Catharsis](http://www.writingthroughlife.com/why-write)*, by Amber Starfire, May 2010.

> Perhaps the most obvious benefit of keeping a personal journal is catharsis. The word “catharsis” originates from the Greek language and means to cleanse or purge...

**Vent** is ([Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/vent))

> 10. to relieve by giving expression to something

See examples at *[I write to vent my frustrations](http://www.experienceproject.com/groups/Write-To-Vent-My-Frustrations/136622)*.

Comment: I'll write this cathartically - it would be nice if down voters had the balls to give a reason, rather than doing a cowardly hit and run.

Comment: I didn't downvote you; I think this is the right answer and just upvoted you. But I have to wonder why, when anonymous downvotes *are part of the SE model*, people always seem to act entitled to an explanation. Whoever downvoted you was no more of a coward than I am, for I often upvote anonymously. *It's the SE model.*

Comment: Yeah, I know. It has been long discussed on meta by people asking the same question. It's not a sense of entitlement that drives my mock frustration. But asking why is also part of the SE model, as is challenging contributors to provide substantive assistance for the betterment of SE and mankind. Thank you for your vote.

Comment: The frustration arises when you can't see *why* there has been a down vote. Anonymous downvotes are more acceptable for wild-guess type of posts,  very short answers that offer no backup or explanation, or posts that are based on personal opinions. I feel better now that I've got it [out of my system](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+out+of+system), phew.

Answer (score 3):

A word you could use is ***journaling***. As this article from [stress.about.com](http://stress.about.com/od/generaltechniques/p/profilejournal.htm) says:

> What Is Journaling?:
>
> Journaling is a term coined for the practice of keeping a diary or
>   journal that explores thoughts and feelings surrounding the events of
>   one’s life. Journaling, as a stress management and self-exploration
>   tool, is not the same as simply recording the happenings in one’s
>   life, like keeping a log. To be most helpful, one must write in detail
>   about feelings and cognitions related to stressful events, as one
>   would discuss topics in therapy.

Also take a look at this article from psychcentral.com : [The Health Benefits of Journaling](http://psychcentral.com/lib/the-health-benefits-of-journaling/000721)

However, 'journaling' could also be used in a generic sense- like maintaining a regular log, that doesn't really have much to do with stress-busting.